# Solving the goat, the wolf and the cabbage problem using A* search

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

In my algorithms course, we were given the challenge of solving the goat, wolf, and cabbage problem using A* search.

The problem statement is as follows:
A farmer wants to transport all three across the river. But if the goat and the cabbage are left alone, the goat will eat the cabbage, and if the wolf and the goat are left alone, the wolf will eat the goat!

I have been struggling to find a meaningful heuristic function for this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A simple heuristic could be the number of items still on the start side of the river, times 2, and minus 1 if the boat is on the same side. So the initial state has heuristic 5.

Comment: This sounds interesting, but why exactly times two and the -1?

Comment: @ShinobiSan How many trips does the farmer have to take when the boat is on the end side?  With no restrictions, 2 trips (back with the boat and forth with the item) for each item on the start side of the river.  If the boat is on the start side, one of those trips already happened.